# Ruby on Rails: How do you list the partial paths that are rendered for a page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to list the partials rendered for each page in my app. For example, when the app/tasks/index.html.erb page is shown, I'd like to show something like the following to the user:

> Partials rendered for this page:
>
> tasks/_list.html.erb
>   tasks/_button.html.erb
>   tasks/_navigation.html.erb

Is there any way to do so in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way, considering that almost those exact lines are printed in the server logs.  I'd start looking at the middleware stack...

Comment: @bdares: It's not in the middleware stack. It's an instrumentation call.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there is so totally a way to do this in Rails!

As bdares pointed out in his comment, the lines for template rendering appear in the logs. But how do they even get there in the first place? Well, that has to do with a [little something in Active Support called `LogSubscriber`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/LogSubscriber.html). The documentation for this is pretty thorough:

> ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber is an object set to consume ActiveSupport::Notifications with the sole purpose of logging them. The log subscriber dispatches notifications to a registered object based on its given namespace.

The thing that's putting the "Rendered ..." lines in the logs, is `ActionView::LogSubscriber` which is defined [like this within Rails 3.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/log_subscriber.rb). Take a moment to read the code. It's nice and neat.

What this is doing is subscribing to a couple of events within Rails, namely the `render_template`, **`render_partial`** and `render_collection` methods. It's doing this by calling the `ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber.attach_to` method, which will attach a log subscriber to some events. That method is also interesting, and defined like this:

```
def attach_to(namespace, log_subscriber=new, notifier=ActiveSupport::Notifications)
  log_subscribers << log_subscriber
  @@flushable_loggers = nil

  log_subscriber.public_methods(false).each do |event|
    next if 'call' == event.to_s

    notifier.subscribe("#{event}.#{namespace}", log_subscriber)
  end
end
```

I've put this code in line because it's *extremely relevant to our interests*. What this is doing is calling `subscribe` on the `notifier` object. The `notifier` object is, by default `ActiveSupport::Notifications`, which is important to remember. The [documentation for that class in Rails is in the API too](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Notifications.html).

When `subscribe` is called, it passes through the name of the `event`. What is this? Well, it's every single public method inside the class. When the `LogSubscriber` subclass is defined, it defines a couple of public methods: `render_template`, **`render_partial`** and `render_collection`. These are the events which will be subscribed to for this log subscriber.

---

Now, that's relevant to our interests because we're going to use the same thing to subscribe to these events inside the view. The first step is letting `ActiveSupport::Notfications` that we want to subscribe to *all* partial rendering events. We can do this by creating a new `before_filter` within `ApplicationController`:

```
before_filter :log_partial_events

def log_partial_events
  @partial_events = []
  ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe("render_partial.action_view") do |event_name, start_at, end_at, id, payload|
  @partial_events << payload[:identifier]
end
```

The event we're subscribing to is the `render_partial` event within the `action_view` namespace, which is exactly one of the events that `ActionView::LogSubscriber` is subscribing to. What will happen when a partial is rendered is that this block will be called and passed in some data.

`event_name`: The name of the event.
`start_at`: The time the event started.
`end_at`: The time the event ended.
`id`: A unique identifier for this event.
`payload`: Some payload information about this event.

When the hook's called, it'll add the `identifier` key from the `payload` to the array defined at the top of the method.

Then in the view, to access a list of these you can do this:

```
<%= debug @partial_events %>
```

Comment: This is wonderful, Ryan! It worked perfectly. Thank you for your incredibly clear tutorial and instructions! :)

Comment: Great tip, thanks! Suggestion: some indentation of the block in your example, or a closing end statement for the method definition, might make it clearer what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

The following example from the [Notification API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Notifications.html) should help you:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe("render") do |*args|
  events << ActiveSupport::Notifications::Event.new(*args)
end
```

For your case (tracking rendered partials) you want the [`'render_partial.action_view'`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html#action-view) notification.  Your code might look something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :subscribe_to_render

  private
  def subscribe_to_render
    @render_events = []
    ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe("render_partial.action_view") do |*args|
      @render_events << ActiveSupport::Notifications::Event.new(*args)
    end
  end
end
```

And wherever you wanted to display this info, you could use this helper method:

```
def display_render_events
  raw(@render_events.map do |event|
    event.payload[:identifier].gsub(/^.*app\/views\//, '')
  end.join('<br/>'))
end
```

Comment: Funny that we had a very similar approach to solving this problem. Great minds and all that :)

Comment: @RyanBigg: thanks for the edit :)  The difference was that I had to actually drill down to find it, while you knew where it was all along.

Comment: Thanks for the link Pinny! You and Ryan are great :)

Comment: I had to drill down too. I had no idea about LogSubscriber, but I did know about ActiveSupport::Notifications before.

Answer (score 2):

For lots of debugging info like this, have a look at [rails-footnotes](https://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes)

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to check [RailsPanel](https://github.com/dejan/rails_panel) which is a Chrome extension.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but in case someone finds this useful a really easy way to list all views and partials being used as you click through your site is to restart your server and only grep for "Rendered" e.g.

```
rails s | grep "Rendered"
```

Comment: Works great and so simple! Thank you James!!